# Sql Exception was unhandled c# log in

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlexception

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= C: \Users\Marco\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HungryGorilla\HungryGorilla\User.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) from [Login] where Username='" + unametxt.Text + "'and Password = '" + pwordtxt.Text + "'",con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

the SDA has error = SqlException was unhandled

Comment: Examine the exception (including the inner exception, if present) and you will see _why_ it failed.

Comment: What is the question? And why is it tagged mysql?

Comment: And don't do SQL injection.

Comment: isn't there a blank space in your SqlConnection Attached DB filename?

Comment: try { ...} catch(SqlException ex)

Comment: @berthos thank you! I already find the error because of you..